# My animations made w/ CSS end abruptly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```css
.topnav {
    background: grey;
}

.topnav li {
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 30px;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor</li>
    <li>Sit</li>
    <li>Amet</li>
</ul>
```

I have a top navigation bar at the beginning of my website. When you hover over a button the background changes colours smoothly. However, when you take the pointer out of the button (stop hovering), the background changes to its default value immediately.

How do I tell my CSS file that I want the background color to return SMOOTHLY to its default value and not to abruptly end?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the animation (transition) to the non-hover state... so it happens on both hover, and unhover. See here:

```
.topnav li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/buc80c7m/

Comment: Thanks! this did solve my problem. However, every time I refresh the page the top navigation bar seem to load from the corner with an animation.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, you could do shorthand for the transition, and have it only affect the background-color:

`transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out`